# Stiff, hard to use poplock, rockshox recon silver

Tags: mountain-bike, suspension, lockout

My bike is equipped  with front suspension Rockshox Recon Silver with PopLock remote lock. The use of that control is VERY stiff and HARD to lock (very easy to unlock though). Every time I need to lock it, I must use carefully my right hand. How can I soften it in order to use it with my single, left thumb? Obviously the problem is not on the lever or its wire, but into the suspension itsself.

Comment: Just to be sure: the cable doesn't do any sharp bends? If I push the fender further in in the setup [here](https://imgur.com/XlQG8DP) and sharpen the bend, I already notice it gets harder to lock. (I'm wondering if at the hardness you describe that should also block the unlock …). Another question is: is the suspension in need of a service? (the rule of thumb I see on the internet is every 50 hours of operation)

Comment: No sharp bends, no need for service. It was hard just from the first day I bought the bicycle, the same hard were all the locks of the bikes in the shops, having that model of suspension.

Comment: Is it hard from the start of motion (spring tension from the shock), or only hard at the very end of travel (Cable adjusted too short)

Comment: It is hard from the start, all the way of the motion. Actually, to check this, I disconected the cable and it is hard to rotate the upper part of the stantion (the part that the cable rotates). So the cable and the remote system is ok.